# Meteor app crashes after being deployed but works on local host

Tags: node.js, meteor

I deployed my meteor app to a .meteor.com server and it states that it is crashing. However, the site works fine on my local machine. Here are the logs:

```
    [Tue Mar 17 2015 20:58:58 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application    on port
     25107
[Tue Mar 17 2015 20:58:58 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS null -> starting
[Tue Mar 17 2015 20:58:58 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS killed -> sleeping
[Tue Mar 17 2015 20:58:58 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> killed
[Tue Mar 17 2015 20:58:58 GMT+0000 (UTC)] NOTICE Starting application on port
9393
[Tue Mar 17 2015 20:58:58 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS null -> starting
[Tue Mar 17 2015 20:58:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO STATUS starting -> crashed
[Tue Mar 17 2015 20:59:31 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT / 174.100.99.102
[Tue Mar 17 2015 20:59:37 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT / 174.100.99.102
[Tue Mar 17 2015 20:59:37 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /favicon.ico 174.100.99.102
[Tue Mar 17 2015 20:59:43 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /favicon.ico 174.100.99.102
[Tue Mar 17 2015 20:59:53 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /_GALAXY_ 174.100.99.102
[Tue Mar 17 2015 20:59:59 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO HIT /_GALAXY_ 174.100.99.102
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I forgot to comment out the email package code and remove the test key. 
Once I did that it deployed fine.